# How to calculate 1 in _______ chance from a percentage?

Tags: probability, statistics, percentages

I am wondering, how do I ago about calculating 1 in chances from a percentage?

**Example:**

- A 1 in 2 chance is 50% and 0.5 as a decimal.

**What I want to do:**

- I have the value 0.1431 (14.3%) and want to convert that into a 1 in chance - any help is much appreciated, thanks.

Comment: $0.5 = 1/2$ is one chance over 2, so if the percentage is $x$ with $x=1/a$ ....

Comment: I think this is rather intuitive: For example $25~\%$ is "one in four", $5~\%$ is "one in 20" ... Can you guess how to calculate these numbers? It involves taking the inverse ...

Comment: Also, do you have requirements that the number should be an integer? Because, obviously, not all percentages (or fractions) can be written as "1 over an integer". For example $0.6667$ is $\frac{2}{3}$ ...

Comment: Thank you very much! So, from the first response, you divide 1 by the decimal if I am correct. For example: if I have 2%, I convert it into a decimal (0.02), then do 1/0.02, which equals 50 - giving the answer: 1 in 50 chance.

Comment: Not bad, but not intuitive enough.  After you convert the percentage $(p)$ into a fraction (typically with a denominator = 100), you end up with an equation like $\frac{1}{n} = \frac{p}{100}.$  This is the **intuition** behind the math.  Once you have *stretched your intuition* here, the math should fall into place.

Comment: Right - that makes more sense. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

A $1$ in $n$ chance can be written as $\frac{1}{n}$. This can be set equal to the probability in decimal form, $p$.

$$p=\frac{p}{1}=\frac{1}{n}$$

You should notice that you are simply finding the reciprocal of $p$ to find $n$. This means that if $p$ is a fraction, you can simply swap the numerator and denominator to get $n$.

Simply divide $1\div p$ to get $n$.

In this example, that means: $$n=1\div0.1431\approx\boxed{6.988}$$

So, $0.1431$ ($14.3\%$) is approximately a $1$ in $6.988$ chance.

Comment: percentages can be tricky :-)